# Passing Prop to a Component inside React Router in React-router version 5.1.2

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

This is specifically for react-router version 5.

I am trying to grab the prop passed to the LandingPage component from React-router. However the LandingPage component do not seem to have the prop value. The only props i see are match,location,history.

My code is fairly straightforward. Kindly let me know what i am missing here?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import landingPageBkg from "../../../public/assets/justice.jpg";



class LandingPage extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.props.history.push('/pagenotfound');
        },3000)
    }
 
  render() {
      console.log('this.props',this.props);
    return (
      <div className="landingPageImg">
        <p> {this.props.text} </p>
        <img src={landingPageBkg} className="landingPageImg"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage;



import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, link, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from '../screens/LandingPage/LandingPage.js'
import PageNotFound from '../screens/PageNotFound/PageNotFound.js'



 const Approutes=(props)=>{
    
    const backgroundImgLoc='../../public/assets/justice.jpg'
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} 
                    render={props => <LandingPage text={backgroundImgLoc} {...props} />}
               
                    />
                    <Route path="/pagenotfound" component={PageNotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default Approutes

import React, { Component } from 'react';
class PageNotFound extends Component {
render() {
   return (
     <div>
      <p style={{color: 'white'}}>PAGE NOT FOUND</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PageNotFound;



import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import '../styles/styles.css'
import Approutes from '../src/routers/Approutes'

ReactDOM.render(<Approutes hi="hiii"/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox?

Comment: I have updated the code. That is all i have in the sandbox. Nothing fancy. Can you make out what is the missing part of the puzzle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `component={LandingPage}` from Route

```
 <Route path="/"    
   exact={true} 
   render={props => <LandingPage text={backgroundImgLoc} 
   {...props} />} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But doesn't the route path attribute needs a corresponding component ?

Comment: You 've used `render`.

Comment: Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop.https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact={true}
            render={props => <LandingPage text={backgroundImgLoc} {...props} />}
          />
          <Route path="/pagenotfound" component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Here is your changed code in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sound-ewbdt